# setting the length and width of scatter plots using R

Tags: r, size, dimension, scatter-plot

I am trying to construct 3 scatter plots together using:

```
par(mfrow=c(3,1)),pty='s')
```

but they appear rather small on an A4 size paper. When I used:

`par(mfrow=c(3,1))` only, the scatter plots were too stretched out (length wise). Is there anything that can be used to allow me to adjust the size so that they are large enough (3 plots) on an A4 size paper?

This is what I am currently using to plot the fist one:

```
(apirt$irt12[apirt$surv==1],
apirt$prtemp[apirt$surv==1],
xlab="ave.base of ears (°C)",
ylab="rectal (°C)",
xlim=c(26,42),
ylim=c(30,42),
col='blue')
```

Thanks,

Baz

Comment: Try with `win.graph(width=12, height=12)` before calling the graph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify the size of the page, somewhere...

```
pdf(file="tmp.pdf",width=21/2,height=29.7/2)
op <- par(mfrow=c(3,1), pty="s")  # or c(2,2) 
plot(1:100,cumsum(rnorm(100)))
plot(1:100,cumsum(rnorm(100)))
plot(1:100,cumsum(rnorm(100)))
par(op)
dev.off()
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using `par(mfrow=c(2,2), pty='s')` instead.  Then you will have  a 2 by 2 layout of the graphs instead (with one empty quadrent), which will give more room for the square plotting regions.  You should also make sure that your plotting device is set up to have the same dimensions as your paper.  Reducing margins will also give you bigger plotting areas (just be sure to leave enough room for the annotations).